# "h2o4gpu-0.1.0-py36-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Tags: h2o, python-wheel

When I try to install:

```
sudo pip3 install h2o4gpu-0.1.0-py36-none-any.whl
```

I get the (not so helpful) error msg:

```
h2o4gpu-0.1.0-py36-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I suspect that this is because I'm running python 3.5 instead of 3.6.  However, when I try to upgrade to python 3.6, I get a stern/scary warning, which I don't know what to do about...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
A plain backport of *just* Python 3.6. System extensions/Python libraries may or may not work.

Don't remove Python 3.5 from your system - it will break.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
```

Googling around for answer, I did come across this, which might indicate that Python 3.5 isn't going to support a 3.6 package:

```
python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pip
>>> print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
[('cp35', 'cp35m', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp35', 'cp35m', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp35', 'abi3', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp35', 'abi3', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp35', 'none', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp35', 'none', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp34', 'abi3', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp34', 'abi3', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp33', 'abi3', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp33', 'abi3', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp32', 'abi3', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp32', 'abi3', 'linux_x86_64'), ('py3', 'none', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('py3', 'none', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp35', 'none', 'any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ('py35', 'none', 'any'), ('py3', 'none', 'any'), ('py34', 'none', 'any'), ('py33', 'none', 'any'), ('py32', 'none', 'any'), ('py31', 'none', 'any'), ('py30', 'none', 'any')]
```

Other system info:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Cuda 8
- cudnn 6
- pip 9.0.1
- Python 3.5
- x86_64
- NVidia 1080

Other notes.  https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu isn't clear about which Python it requires, although I suspect the file name makes this clear.  (I also guess that this means h2o4gpu won't work on Python 2.7).

The README file is not explicit about what nccl is.  From Google, I'm guessing that it means nccl is for having more than one GPU (I have only one.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  (Sorry I could add h2o4gpu tag because I don't have enough reputation points.)

Comment: Hey Clem, the readme does say that the downloada are “For Python 3.6“ so as you noticed you won’t be able to use it with 2.7/3.5. We recommend installing python 3.6 and making a pyenv or virtualenv with it for h2o4gpu. As for NCCL, good point we’ll add a link. it is indeed required for multi GPU systems.

Answer (score 0):

The [recommended way](https://askubuntu.com/a/865569/93794) to run python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 is to use the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6 (and remember you then need to run it with `python3.6`).

For 16.10 and 17.04 you don't need the ppa and can just do `sudo apt-get install python3.6`

Alternatively, upgrade your system to Ubuntu 17.10, and then python 3.6 will be the system python.  (17.10 is not a long-term support release, so plan to then upgrade to 18.04 LTS when it comes out in April.)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figure this out:

```
# if you don't have virtualenv installed:
sudo apt-get install virtualenv

virtualenv -p python3.6 py_36_env
# Then activate the environment:
source ~/py_36_env/bin/activate
```

Once in the environment, then following the instructions for your specific system:  https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu